# Restore Nintex forms & Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, nintex

I'm migrating my site collection to a new farm and the site collection content database is the only thing I have. Nintex Forms and Nintex Workflow configuration databases are not available.

Is there any way to recover forms and workflows even partially?

thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 0):

As previous project we migrate Nintex Workflow and Forms by Import/Export by powershell and backup/restore Nintex DB Config and mapped Nintex DB for Site Collection in this case it is work fine but for Flexi Task Forms need import manually from old Workflow of each task for and export manually to a new Workflow on a new environment. Let me know if you need scripts then I can share them with you.

Comment: Thank you Victor for the time and the reply! In my case Nintex Config databases aren't available so the use of scripts wouldn't be the solution.
I am more thinking of downloading XML files maybe for the forms and importing them manually one by one.
And something like that for the workflows.

Comment: Yep it's works if you have not big work flows and forms